# tarfile.addfile gives error: TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

This is my first post about Python, and I'm kind of new to it.

Unfortunately I need to use Windows as my OS.
I'm using python 3.3.2 from python.org.

I'm trying to create a tar file from memory, adding a FILE.txt to it.

```
from io import StringIO
import tarfile

archive_files = []

data = ["DATA1 "]
data.append("DATA2 ")
archive_files.append(("FILE.txt", "\n".join(data)))

tar = tarfile.open ("file.tar", "w:tar")
for name, data in archive_files:
    info = tarfile.TarInfo(name)
    info.size = len(data)
    tar.addfile(info, StringIO(data))
tar.close()
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 420, in run_nodebug
  File "C:\home\rs94036\src\python\testTar.py", line 14, in <module>
    tar.addfile(info, StringIO(data))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tarfile.py", line 1957, in addfile
    copyfileobj(fileobj, self.fileobj, tarinfo.size)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tarfile.py", line 274, in copyfileobj
    dst.write(buf)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I know my problem is in the line 14, but I can't understand what's wrong.
This code is used in Linux, specifically in pacman (ArchLinux package manager automated tests).

Can someone help me?

Thanks,
Renan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write `bytes` to a tar file, not `str`, so you have to encode your data before you write it to a tar file. (Encoding of your choice, I used `utf-8` in the example)

Problematic lines:

```
info.size = len(data)
tar.addfile(info, StringIO(data))
```

Should be something like:

```
encoded = data.encode('utf-8')
info.size = len(encoded)
tar.addfile(info, BytesIO(encoded))
```

Comment: @Viktor Kerkez: How can I determine that encoding? ```UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 15: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: @luckydonald There isn't any 100% correct way for determining encoding. There are some libraries that try to do that, but if you don't know it in advance it can be a huge problem.